# Does .container have a special meaning in CSS, Electron, or Chromium?

Tags: html, css, node.js, electron, chromium

I'm a programmer with background in C++ and Python who's learning JS, HTML, and CSS. I'm currently learning Electron through a book called *Electron in Action*.  One of the examples contains an HTML code, as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Fire Sale</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="controls">
            <button id="new-file">New File</button>
            <button id="open-file">Open File</button>
            <button id="save-markdown">Save File</button>
            <button id="revert">Revert</button>
            <button id="save-html">Save HTML</button>
            <button id="show-file">Show File</button>
            <button id="open-in-default">Open in Default Application</button>

        </section>

        <section class="content">
            <label for="markdown" hidden>Markdown Content</label>
            <textarea class="raw-markdown" id="markdown"></textarea>
            <div class="rendered-html" id="html"></div>

        </section>
    </body>
    <script>
        require('./renderer');
    </script>
</html>
```

And its stylesheet is as follows:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body , input {
    font: menu;
}

textarea, input, div, button {
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.controls {
    background-color: rgb(217, 241, 238);
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

button {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(181, 220, 216);
}

button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(156,, 198, 192);
}

button:active {
    background-color: rgb(144, 182, 177);
}
button:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(196, 204, 202);
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.raw-markdown, .rendered-html {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: scroll;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.raw-markdown {
    border: 5px solid rgb(238, 252, 250);;
    background-color: rgb(238, 252, 250);
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Notice that there's an extra class in the CSS file, which is not to be found in the HTML specification.  Since the author is yet to update the example's repository, I must ask: does .container carry some sort of special  meaning in CSS? I googled, and nothing came up, so I guess it doesn't, but it would be safe to ask, since I have searched the book, and there's no other mention of this alluring container class. Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 3):

CSS class names can be just about anything, there are no reserved classes or special classes to watch out for. So `.container` is just targeting any element with `class="container"`, that is it!

Comment: To add to this: the container class is used very often. Again, it is not special or reserved. You can find .container and variants of it used on many popular sites, and you can see it being used by bootstrap here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/

Comment: But that's my point. There's no element with that classname in the HTML file. Why?

Comment: The reason you don't see a `.container` in that page could be: ***a)*** there used to be one but got deleted and CSS wasn't cleaned (CSS weight is one of the last concerns in web optimization - because it almost doesn't count). Or ***b)*** that stylesheet is used by more than one page. And one of them has a `.container`.

Comment: Perhaps the author of the book is using `.container` as a ez reference to whatever container element. Funny thing about CSS code, it is all too common to have unused CSS as a project changes and evolves over time. The unused CSS just creates bloat in the size of your project, no other harm done by it's mere presence.

Comment: I just found the repository and indeed, it was reserved for something in the future. Thanks guys.